# Project Euler #23 in JS

Tags: javascript

My results for numbers between 1 and 28321 (limit)

- sum of all numbers: 395465626
- sum of all abundant numbers: 392188885
- sum of all non abundant numbers: **3276741** (correct answer is 4179871)

```js
var divisors = function(number){ 
sqrtNumber = Math.sqrt(number);
var sum = 1;
for(var i = 2; i<= sqrtNumber; i++) 
{
    if (number == sqrtNumber * sqrtNumber) 
    {
        sum += sqrtNumber;
        sqrtNumber--;
    }
    if( number % i == 0 )
    {
        sum += i + (number/i); 
    }       
}
    
    if (sum > number) {return true;}
    else {return false;}
};

var abundent = [], k = 0;
var upperLimit = 28123;
for (var i = 1; i <= upperLimit; i++)
{
 if (divisors(i)) 
    {abundent[k] = i; k++};
    
} 

var abundentCount = abundent.length;
var canBeWrittenAsAbundant = []; 
for (var i = 0; i < abundentCount; i++){
    for (var j = i; j < abundentCount; j++){
         if (abundent[i] + abundent[j] <= upperLimit){canBeWrittenAsAbundant[abundent[i]+abundent[j]] = true;}
     else {
        break;
      }
   }
}

for (i=1; i <= upperLimit; i++){
    if (canBeWrittenAsAbundant[i] == true){continue;}
    else {canBeWrittenAsAbundant[i] = false;}
}

var sum = 0;
for (i=1; i <= upperLimit; i++)
{
    
    if (!canBeWrittenAsAbundant[i]){
        sum += i;
    }
}

 console.log(sum);
```

I'm using http://www.mathblog.dk/project-euler-23-find-positive-integers-not-sum-of-abundant-numbers/ as guidance, but my results are different. I'm a pretty big newb in the programming community so please keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to calculate the sum of all numbers using a cycle, since there is a formula, like this:

> 1 + 2 + ... + number = (number * (number + 1)) / 2

Next, let's take a look at divisors:

```
var divisors = function(number){ 
sqrtNumber = Math.sqrt(number);
var sum = 1;
for(var i = 2; i<= sqrtNumber; i++) 
{
    if (number == sqrtNumber * sqrtNumber) 
    {
        sum += sqrtNumber;
        sqrtNumber--;
    }
    if( number % i == 0 )
    {
        sum += i + (number/i); 
    }       
}

    if (sum > number) {return true;}
    else {return false;}
};
```

You initialize sum with 1, since it is a divisor. However, I do not quite understand why do you iterate until the square root instead of the half of the number. For example, if you call the function for 100, then you are iterating until `i` reaches 10. However, 100 is divisible with 20 for example. Aside of that, your function is not optimal. You should `return true` as soon as you found out that the `number` is abundant. Also, the name of `divisors` is misleading, you should name your `function` with a more significant name, like `isAbundant`. Finally, I do not understand why do you decrease square root if `number` happens to be its exact square and if you do so, why do you have this check in the cycle. Implementation:

```
var isAbundant = function(number) {
    var sum = 1;
    var half = number / 2;
    for (var i = 2; i <= half; i++) {
        if (number % i === 0) {
            sum += i;
            if (sum > number) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Note, that perfect numbers are not considered to be abundant by the function.

You do not need to store all numbers, since you are calculating aggregate data. Instead, do it like this:

```
//we assume that number has been initialized
console.log("Sum of all numbers: " + ((number * (number + 1)) / 2));
var abundantSum = 0;
var nonAbundantSum = 0;
for (var i = 0; i <= number) {
    if (isAbundant(i)) {
        abundantSum += i;
    } else {
        nonAbundantSum += i;
    }
}
console.log("Sum of non abundant numbers: " + nonAbundantSum);
console.log("Sum of abundant numbers: " + abundantSum);
```

Code is not tested. Also, beware overflow problems and structure your code.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the Corrected Code for NodeJS..

```
    var divisors = function (number) {
    sqrtNumber = Math.sqrt(number);
    var sum = 1;
    var half = number / 2;
    for (var i = 2; i <= half; i++) {
        if (number % i === 0) { sum += i; }
    }
    if (sum > number) { return true; }
    else { return false; }
};
var abundent = [], k = 0;
var upperLimit = 28123;
for (var i = 1; i <= upperLimit; i++) {
    if (divisors(i)) { abundent[k] = i; k++ };
}
var abundentCount = abundent.length;
var canBeWrittenAsAbundant = [];
for (var i = 0; i < abundentCount; i++) {
    for (var j = i; j < abundentCount; j++) {
        if (abundent[i] + abundent[j] <= upperLimit) { canBeWrittenAsAbundant[abundent[i] + abundent[j]] = true; }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }
}
for (i = 1; i <= upperLimit; i++) {
    if (canBeWrittenAsAbundant[i] == true) { continue; }
    else { canBeWrittenAsAbundant[i] = false; }
}

var sum = 0;
for (i = 1; i <= upperLimit; i++) {
    if (!canBeWrittenAsAbundant[i]) {
        sum += i;
    }
}

console.log(sum);
```

Comment: Can you please only post [in English](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/262054/7508700) on Stack Overflow.